# Yii2, setFlash() doesn't keep value

Tags: session, yii2, flash-message

Something strange happens to me when using the function `Yii::$app->setFlash()`. The value  is not preserved.

In the my class filter I try validate some condition and report a mistake by flash message, redirecting to some URL where I can show this message friendly.

```
class filterTime extends ActionFilter
{
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        //Evaluate some condition then fire 
        //message
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', "this is a error message");    
        return Yii::$app->controller->redirect(Url::toRoute('/masters/workers'));
    }

    public function afterAction($action, $result)
    {
        return parent::afterAction($action, $result);
    }
}
```

After this has redirect to new  address , nothing is shown. Nothing is shown. This although I have put the div to show this message in the view of the new address:

```
<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('error')): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
         <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('error') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're using `beforeAction()` in a wrong way. `beforeAction()` should return boolean - if you want to prevent real action execution, you should return `false`:

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    if (/* some condition */) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'this is a error message');  
        // setup response for redirection
        Yii::$app->controller->redirect(Url::toRoute('/masters/workers'));
        return false;
    }  

     return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this way to keep `flash` while redirecting on to another page:

```
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'this is a error message', false); // false keep that message
```

Hope that help you.

Comment: that wont clear the flash once displayed and will show on every refresh, which isnt what OP is intended to do, he isnt able to display it even once.

Comment: That is from docs: `Whether the flash message should be automatically removed only if it is accessed. If false, the flash message will be automatically removed after the next request, regardless if it is accessed or not. If true (default value), the flash message will remain until after it is accessed.`

Comment: yes you are right about that part, that it will remove and wont show up again, butthe thing is even if you try with your code the message wont show up either you pass `false` or not. returning `false` from the `beforeAction` will enable the flash message display otherwise nothing will work

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam i agree with you about return `false` in `beforeRequest`, My answer works on most cases, because you can specify the flash message at the action which it trigger and make a redirect, and at the new action it will fire up. After that this message will be removed from the section.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco It does not make much sense - using `false` as third argument of `setFlash()` will only increase chances that it disappear, since flash may be removed even if you never display it.

Comment: @rob006 it does make sense when you show your flash at the time when you call action, but.. if you (not assign `false` at the end), and redirect, you never get this flash, and that what i mentioned above, it was taken from official documentation, and that's how i do my flashes when i need to redirect to another action.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I'm not sure what do you mean. If you use `true`, flash will be removed only after you call `getFlash()`. If you use `false` flash will be removed on next request regardless of whether it was accessed or not. There is no case when using `false` will preserve flash while using `true` will not.

Comment: @rob006, you are right, `request->action (you show flash, true)->flash shows right away`, in case if you make `(request->action->model saved->(no flashes at this point, right?)->setFlash(xxx,xxx,false)->redirect('action'))` and at the new view you have this action fire up, over wise you will not see it.